# HTTP ERROR: 500  Severe errors in solr configuration

Tags: lucene, solr

i am trying to import data from mysql following this link
http://www.cabotsolutions.com/blog/200905/using-solr-lucene-for-full-text-search-with-mysql/
I am getting the following error..

```
HTTP ERROR: 500 - Severe errors in solr configuration. Check your log files for more detailed information on what may be wrong.
If you want solr to continue after configuration errors, change:  <abortOnConfigurationError>false</abortOnConfigurationError> in solr.xml
-------------------------------------------------------------
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:239)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:283)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:124)
    at org.apache.solr.core.Config.<init>(Config.java:110)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig.<init>(SolrConfig.java:130)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:401)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:280)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:195)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$Initializer.initialize(CoreContainer.java:113)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.init(SolrDispatchFilter.java:86)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:99)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:594)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:139)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:500)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:448)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:147)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:161)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:147)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:117)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:210)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
    at org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:929)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:183)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:497)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.main(Main.java:115)

RequestURI=/solr/admin/
```

Please guide me to solve this
Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Your solrconfig.xml is not well-formed. It is an XML parsing error and in fact, it has nothing to do with Solr.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

`<entity name="id" query="SELECT * FROM table_name">`

Shouldnt that be with an / at the end. ???

`<entity name="id" query="SELECT * FROM table_name"/>`

Just my thought